# Cython iterate over list of numpy arrays without the gil

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

I would like to iterate over a list of numpy arrays with different dimensions, and pass them in to a cython function that does not require the GIL:

```
# a has T1 rows and M columns
a = np.array([[0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7],
              [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6],
              [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6]])

# b has T2 rows and M columns
b = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6]])

# c has T3 rows and M columns
c = np.array([[0.1, 0.0, 0.3, 0.6],
              [0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.0],
              [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0]])

array_list = [a, b, c]
N = len(array_list)

# this function works
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef void function_not_requiring_the_gil(double[:, ::1] arr) nogil:
    cdef int T = arr.shape[0]
    cdef int M = arr.shape[1]
    cdef int i, t

    for t in range(T):
        for i in range(M):
            # do some arbitrary thing to the array in-place
            arr[t, i] += 0.001

# issue is with this function
def function_with_loop_over_arrays(array_list, int N):
    cdef int i

    with nogil:
        for i in range(N):
            function_not_requiring_the_gil(array_list[i])
```

When I compile the Cython code, I get the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def function_with_loop_over_arrays(array_list, int N):
    cdef int i

    with nogil:
        for i in range(N):
            function_not_requiring_the_gil(array_list[i])                                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

my_file.pyx:312:53: Indexing Python object not allowed without gil
```

Is there another type of data structure that I can use instead of a Python list to store these numpy arrays so that I can iterate over them without the gil? I'm open to suggestions involving malloc C pointers/Cython memoryviews/other types I'm not aware of.

Note that each numpy array has a different number of rows, but the length of the list of arrays is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass two arrays of shape `(3,)` to `function_with_loop_over_arrays`: one (`array_starts`) which contains pointers to the first element of `a`, `b` and `c`, and one (`arrays_rows`) which contains `T1`, `T2` and `T3`.

Then modify `function_not_requiring_the_gil` so that it receives a pointer on the first element of the array and its number of rows, and you will be able to call it in `function_with_loop_over_arrays` with:

```
for i in range(N):  # N is 3 and should be passed to function_with_loop_over_arrays
    function_not_requiring_the_gil(array_starts[i], array_rows[i])
```

Comment: @B.M. Well I added a comment explaining why I downvoted your answer. Is there any issue?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, it does address my question but will require modifying the nogil function to take in different arguments. I actually have several nogil functions that I want to call in this loop, and each of them takes multiple arrays as input, so having to pass in two arguments (start pointer and number of rows) for each of the original arrays would really balloon the number of arguments to these functions. Is there any way that I can still pass in the arrays/memoryviews themselves? If not, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @user3570195 I don't believe there's a way of manipulating arrays in cython without passing their length: that's how C behaves, if I'm not mistaken. That's even how blas/lapack routine function calls are made in cython.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your approach now, but am not very familiar with C. Just to be clear, it will require me to pass in double* pointers to my numpy arrays, and then change my nogil function to access the array as arr[(t*M)+i] rather than arr[t, i]? A more explicit explanation of the changes required would be much appreciated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you can't index a Python `list` without the gil, and there aren't really any obvious alternative data-structures that fill the same role. You just need to move the `nogil` to take the indexing outside it

```
def function_with_loop_over_arrays(array_list, int N):
    cdef int i
    cdef double[:, ::1] tmp_mview

    for i in range(N):
        tmp_mview = array_list[i]
        with nogil:        
            function_not_requiring_the_gil(tmp_mview)
```

(Equivalently you can put the indexing inside a `with gil:` block instead.)

There's a small cost to getting and releasing the `gil` but provided your `function_not_requiring_the_gil` does a decent amount of work compared to the indexing it should be insignificant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood the problem with using a list, that's why I asked for an alternative way of passing in my arrays. I would like to release the GIL for that loop because I'll be passing in many arrays and want to use multithreading. The answer @P. Camilleri provided is closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: You can still use multithreading. It'll be slightly slower because it'll have to wait occasionally for each thread to get the GIL, but it will still give you most of the expected speed up.

Answer (score -4):

`nogil` features are often easy to control from [numba](http://numba.pydata.org) :

```
import numba
@numba.jit(nogil=True) 
def function_not_requiring_the_gil(arr):
    T,N = arr.shape
    for t in range(T):
        for i in range(N):
        # do some arbitrary thing to the array in-place
        arr[t, i] += 0.001

def function_with_loop_over_arrays(array_list)
        for a in array_list:
            function_not_requiring_the_gil(a)
```

will give you the same (efficient) result.

Comment: I don't think this addresses my question. What you propose only takes in a single numpy array, rather than an arbitrary list of arrays. The nogil function that I have is actually much more complicated, and I have several of them. The issue is that I would like to call these nogil functions on many numpy arrays of different sizes in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer, it now seems to address my question. However, I would really like to know if there is a way to accomplish this with cython rather than numba, because the nogil functions that I need to call in a loop are already implemented.

Comment: I have downvoted because I believe the question rather explicitly asks for a Cython solution, not a numba one.